# Divide one value by another to display a percentage

Tags: sql

I'm having difficulty coding to output the correct percentage.

```
Bet     Profit  ROI 
142 13.4580 55.4580
```

roi should be `13.4580 / 142 = .095` to nearest 2 dec places
The formula below displays `roi = 154.4580`

Can you please correct bottom line (ROI) it should be Profit/Bet = (ROI)  Many thanks

```
SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), 
  Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Roi = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER () /COUNT(*)  OVER ()
```

Tried several times without success

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, Postgresql, etc). Can you also update your question with the full, valid, SQL statement you are running - what you've posted is obviously incomplete as it doesn't include a FROM clause

Comment: Hi, same as @NickW, please put some datas as well to have some understanding of your context. TY.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2018 version sample data   BET 142, PROFIT, 13.4580 ROI should be  0.095 Cheers

Comment: Some data from your source tables that is being selected in your SQL (i.e. from the BetfairWinSP column) - not the results of your calculated columns. You also haven't fixed your SQL statement. FYI - you should always update your question with any new information (rather than add it in comments) so that all the information needed to help you is in one place

Comment: Apologies Nick but that is beyond my capacity. I had thought it would be a matter of modifying the line beginning with ROI = which to me seemed a simple division however it seems I am wrong. Never mind I will skip that column and perform that in Excel. Thanks for your input. Cheers Ian.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the calculation should be straightforward, like `Roi = Profit / Bet`
So I suggest to try the code below:

```sql
SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), 
  Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Roi = Profit / Bet
```

Edit: how about using the WITH statement?

```sql
WITH temp_table AS (
SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), 
  Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER ()
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT Roi = Profit / Bet FROM temp_table
```

Comment: I did try using Profit / Bet but they are not recognised columns.

Comment: how about using the WITH statement? (see edit above)

Comment: Just kept getting syntax errors and in the end gave up. But thanks for the help. Ian

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error near the word OVER.  I'm guessing its the last or second last over of the code. Any ideas ?   WITH temp_table AS (
SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), 
  Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), 
  Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 
  THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () -  COUNT(*) OVER ()
  FROM dbo.[AAAA-UKHR-TEMPLATE]
)
SELECT Roi = Profit / Bet FROM temp_table OVER (),

Comment: why do you have to add `OVER ()` in the final statement `SELECT Roi = Profit / Bet FROM temp_table OVER ()`?

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for the past few days. I removed the Over () from the final statement

Comment: Still getting a bracket ')' error ( ([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT() OVER ()

Comment: That means unequal number of open and close brackets. There are 13 pairs of `(` and `)` in the WITH statement code block. Can you check your code also?